# Proving general property of power set of set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm taking an introductory course in set theory. We were presented with the following property for the power set of the difference between sets:

$$\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B ) \subseteq (\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\mathcal{P}(B)) \cup \ \{\varnothing\}$$

The prove was not given or attempted. I can formulate multiple examples that satisfy the propoerty but can't come up with a formal demonstration. I would like to know how it can be proved, as I don't know how to start with the demonstration.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you want to prove that for two sets $R$ and $S$ you have $R \subseteq S$ a formal proof usually loos like this: "Let $x$ be an element of $R$. Then (argument using $x$ here ...) so $x$ is also an element of $S$." Try that. [edit] the question to show us what you did if you get stuck.

Comment: In general, when working on inclusion or equality problems in elementary set theory you should start by writing out what the sets are. for example $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus \mathcal{P}(B)=\{ S\subseteq A : S\not\subseteq B\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where exactly you're running into trouble, but from the fact that you can generate examples, it seems that you at least understand the statement. With that said, I suspect the following hint might be useful.

To prove that $\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B ) \subseteq (\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\mathcal{P}(B)) \cup \ \{\varnothing\}$, it suffices to show that for any $S \in \mathcal P(A \setminus B)$ with $S \neq \varnothing$, $S \in \mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)$. In other words: show that if $S \subseteq A \setminus B$ with $S \neq \varnothing$, then it holds that $S \subseteq A$ and it is not the case that $S \subseteq B$. It is useful to note that if $A \setminus B$ is non-empty, then there exists at least one element $x$ such that $x \in A$ but $x \notin B$.

Comment: Please do not answer when *anything in a question* is not clear.  Instead, ask the OP for clarification.